# Open ng2-bootstrap-modal dialogservice from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I have an Angular component like this:

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() TestData: TestObject[];
    constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.RenderTreeView();
        $('#treeviewStandard').treeview('collapseAll', { silent: true });
    }

    RenderTreeView() {
        $('#treeviewStandard').treeview({
            data: this.TestData,         
            onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.isOverlaid) {
                    //testPopup isnt opening ng2-bootstrap-modal since this is angular 2 function 
                    //and dialogService is unknown to javascript 
                    this.testPopup();
                }
            }
        });        
    }

    testPopup() {       
        this.dialogService.addDialog(PopupComponent, {
            majorObject: this.TestData,
            moduleType:"check"
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to open `ng2-bootstrap-modal` popup in callback method `onNodeSelected` treeview, but `testPopup()` function cannot be called and it displays:

> Cannot read property 'testPopup' of undefined.

Is there any way to call an Angular2 component function from JavaScript code? Or isn't my approach to generate treeview so much *Angular* way?

Comment: the this is not a reference of the method so it is undefined , make use of `ngAfterviewInit` instead of ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fat arrow  =>` syntax instead of using `function`.

```
onNodeSelected: (event, data) =>{

            console.log(data);
            if(data.isOverlaid)
            {
                    //testPopup isnt opening ng2-bootstrap-modal since this is angular 2 function 
                    //and dialogService is unknown to javascript 
                    this.testPopup();
            }
    }
```

Alternatively you can store a `this` object in some variable and try it.

```
var self = this;

onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.isOverlaid)
                 {
                        self.testPopup();  // called using variable
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` value in `function` is not pointing to your class instance, you should use arrow function instead:

```
RenderTreeView() {
    $('#treeviewStandard').treeview({
        data: this.TestData,         
        onNodeSelected: (event, data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.isOverlaid)
                {
                    //testPopup isnt opening ng2-bootstrap-modal since this is angular 2 function 
                    //and dialogService is unknown to javascript 
                    this.testPopup();
                }
          }
    });        
}
```